# AngularJS Separating The Controllers, Argument is not a function, it is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I know it is asked hundreds of times, but I cannot really find out the error. I have looked all the similar questions At first, I did everything in one page, it was working, but obviously I needed to learn to separate my controllers to different files. I have did the following:

**partials/hosts.html:**

```
Hosts Page
<div ng-controller="HostsCtrl">
    {{ title }}
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myApp.js"></script>
    <script src="js/HostsCtrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="MyApp">
...
```

**js/MyApp.js**

Create `MyApp` module, and a submodule named `controllers`

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
console.log("index.js file loaded");

angular.module('MyApp.controllers', []);
```

**js/HostsCtrl.js**

Just a simple controller in `MyApp.controllers` module that displays hello world and time.

```
console.log("HostsCtrl.js file loaded");
angular.module('MyApp.controllers').controller("HostsCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Hello world" + new Date().getTime();
});
```

***The console output:***

```
index.js file loaded MyApp.js:2
HostsCtrl.js file loaded HostsCtrl.js:1
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'HostsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

I assume the loading order is correct, however I do not understand why it gives an error and cannot resolve HostsCtrl. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you never declare `MyApp.controllers` dependency (since your controllers are in separate module). Try this:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [
    'ngRoute', 
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'MyApp.controllers'
]);
```

Comment: You are right, it solved it. However, I wonder, I declared this as a dependency here but the `MyApp.controllers` declaration is after this line, how come it does not give an error, possibly saying "you dont have MyApp.controllers yet, no way to depend on them"